# Could matter be simply spatial geometry, and nothing else?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, curvature, matter

As it will become evident by my question, I have no degree in physics or math.

Question: could matter be nothing more than the curvature of space? In that case, different atoms and different combinations of atoms would tell space how to curve in a very, very specific ways. So, by looking at your computer screen, you are simply looking at the space-time fabric in front of you bent/shaped in a particular way.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_electron for some speculative ideas that are non-mainstream.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that mass could be due to curvature dates back to the very beginnings of general relativity. Einstein himself put lots of effort into finding a way to represent matter in a geometrical way. However all such efforts have failed and as far as I know this approach has been abandoned.

There is a recent review of the area in the talk [Matter from Space by Domenico Giulini](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.2574) though this is rather technical and will be incomprehensible to non-physicists.